# Change Order Totals block in Admin > Sales > Order > View

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I'm trying to edit the order totals temporarily on the fly.
See screenshot of what I'm trying to edit.
I have looked at the events, but none I could find that wouldn't affect the rest of the sites, nor could I find the page that handles this.

Any help with this?

[image: Order View]
<sub>(source: [ctrlv.in](http://img.ctrlv.in/4f16f663d2138.PNG))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to identify the page that handles this is turn on the template hints for the admin area by executing the following query against the magento db

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1), ('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

You'll then be able to determine the relevant template to override.

In this case it's **/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml**

You can turn off the template hints by running

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path like 'dev/debug/template_hints%';
```

Comment: Any way of finding out where this template file is called? Because I need this to be an extension.

Comment: Seems it's only in layout, any way I can find out where this is being called?

Comment: it's defined in the /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml with a name of **order_totals**, you should be able to override this in your extensions layout files